# Sidebar formatting issues

Tags: 6, nodes, routes, navigation

The Drupal 6 website I am working on is giving me some problems with the sidebars.

Here, my 'general info' sidebar is incorrectly showing 'home' sidebar info.

To the right is my 'divisions' sidebar which displays correctly [except for the >> next to probate, can't seem to find a fix for that issue]

[image: apppeals sidebar]
[image: general info sidebar]

I've tried to go through general info and compare the node hierarchy with that of divisions, making sure the settings are similar. I did not seem to find anything that would fix the issue for me.

Also if anyone could help me with why the ">>" 's show up seemingly randomly ( see 'Human Resources', 'Juvenile Delinquency Court', and 'Records management') These nodes do not have children.

[First sidebar issue](http://dev.sjcourts.org/appeals)
[Second sidebar issue](http://dev.sjcourts.org/human-resources)

Comment: ">>" it shows, because of the active li class.

Comment: I used firebug to see that only 'Human Resources' had the active class. And even without being active, 'Resources and Related Websites' still had a unexplained '>>'

Comment: can you link your website in comment

Comment: I just added them in an edit  but on this page you can really see the issue: http://dev.sjcourts.org/appeals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your css file and it shows because of below css line, That arrow is activated for last li item, just delete or comment the lines.

```
#leftNav ul ul ul li.last a {
    background-color: rgb(190, 205, 222);
    background-image: url("img/blue/icon-leftnav.gif");
}
```

Probably you have to edit under themes folder or modules menu folder.

Go to your themes folder sites/all/themes/yourtheme/blue.css and search for **url("img/blue/icon-leftnav.gif")** or line 13 and comment the line and then clear the cache.

Comment: I deleted the css you showed me but it didn't help much. http://dev.sjcourts.org/appeals

Comment: now the arrow is not showing for me, you have to clear the cache and clear your browser by ctrl+shift+delete

Comment: Ok i see. It did solve the double arrow problem but there is still something wrong with the navbar. Although I'm on the page of a 'divisions' child page, it is displaying the child pages of general info as well.

Comment: @NSchleder have you created separate tpl file for appeals ?

Comment: No. I don't have a separate tpl file for appeals

Comment: @NSchleder I tried, but no luck, I will check another day

Comment: I think I found the issue. It had something to do with me moving the page from the child of the Home page to the child of a Divisions page. Didn't find a solution- ended up deleting then remaking the entire page.